# Download failed. Obtain the jar manually and place it at ./.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I'm trying to run ./sbt file it throw an error

```
Detected sbt version 0.12.2
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
Downloading sbt launcher 0.12.2:
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar
    To  ./.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar
Download failed. Obtain the jar manually and place it at ./.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was manually **sbt-launch.jar** placed in  **./.lib/0.12.2/** directory then its working fine.

```
./.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar
```